# How do I freeze javascript as soon as a page loads

Tags: javascript, html

There is a webpage that displays content extremely briefly before the javascript kicks in and removes the content. I've tried sniping it with inspect element and disabling javascript, but the script is too fast and the page checks to ensure javascript is enabled. Is there any way to freeze javascript the moment the page loads? I have a fair amount of experience with web programming both making websites and extensions, I just can find no method to achieve this.

Comment: I think you can add a breakpoint in debugger and inspect the content while JS is paused

Comment: Maybe NoScript could help you out here. This way it will never ever execute the javascript as it's disabling it.